# Can't write HTML in React Components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using React without Node, or any other thing (I cannot use it, they asked me to do use react in this way in my job... nothing I can do about it), I am using a HTML file with references to different scripts.

So, I managed to make this code work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTML with multiple scripts using React.js</h1>
    <p>React.js without Node.js or any other thing</p>
    <p>React.js is loaded as script tags.</p>
    <div id="like_button_container"></div>
    <div id="like_button_container2"></div>
    <script src="like_button.js"></script>
    <script src="like_button2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

like_button.js :

```
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Like'
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

like_button2.js (yes is an H1, not a button, just testing):

```
'use strict';

const f = React.createElement;

class LikeButton2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return f(
      'h1',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Like'
    );
  }
}

const domContainer2 = document.querySelector('#like_button_container2');
ReactDOM.render(f(LikeButton2), domContainer2);
```

However, I cannot write "normal" HTML in the return of the component, cause it won't render and will give me an error:

```
return f(
      <div>LOL</div>
    );
```

Pic of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgQvb.png

How can I solve this? is really limitating and awful to write HTMl within quotation marks... remember, cannot use Node or any other thing.

And also, ¿how can I render everything within the same div? If I try to render both components on the same div, it only renders the first script but the weird part is that one script is "aware" of the existence of the other (can't use same name for variables, for example).

Thank you in advance, I'm really suffering with this.

Comment: Can't use jsx either, forgot to mention that.

Comment: You cannot use HTML in reactJs you have to use Jsx and for Jsx you have to use babel plugin to transpile jsx to js.

Comment: I have to try more... but, do you know how to render both components on the same div?

Comment: You ca create a parent component and wrap both component in it and render the parent component .

Comment: I though about that but I don't know if my boss will like it... we'll see.

Comment: remove the f from the return ..... return (
      <div>LOL</div>
    );

Comment: @KeatonBenning, didn't work.

Comment: Is it a requirement to have 2 separate "button" files?

Comment: @MattCarlotta no, this is just a testing. But the components need to be in separated files.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that support for `import` statements is limited to more modern browsers. So if you want to keep the elements within the same `div id="root"`, then you'll either have to define them within the same file or use a third-party library. That said, [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) isn't valid HTML, so you're either stuck forcing users to transpile the JSX into valid JS **for every visit** (bad -- slow performance, unoptimized code, and waste of bandwidth), or you're going to want to [compile](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#compile-files) your JSX into a minified/optimized js file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    "use strict";function _instanceof(e,t){return null!=t&&"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&t[Symbol.hasInstance]?!!t[Symbol.hasInstance](e):e instanceof t}function _typeof(e){return(_typeof="function"==typeof Symbol&&"symbol"==typeof Symbol.iterator?function(e){return typeof e}:function(e){return e&&"function"==typeof Symbol&&e.constructor===Symbol&&e!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof e})(e)}function _classCallCheck(e,t){if(!_instanceof(e,t))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}function _defineProperties(e,t){for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){var i=t[n];i.enumerable=i.enumerable||!1,i.configurable=!0,"value"in i&&(i.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(e,i.key,i)}}function _createClass(e,t,n){return t&&_defineProperties(e.prototype,t),n&&_defineProperties(e,n),e}function _possibleConstructorReturn(e,t){return!t||"object"!==_typeof(t)&&"function"!=typeof t?_assertThisInitialized(e):t}function _getPrototypeOf(e){return(_getPrototypeOf=Object.setPrototypeOf?Object.getPrototypeOf:function(e){return e.__proto__||Object.getPrototypeOf(e)})(e)}function _assertThisInitialized(e){if(void 0===e)throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");return e}function _inherits(e,t){if("function"!=typeof t&&null!==t)throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function");e.prototype=Object.create(t&&t.prototype,{constructor:{value:e,writable:!0,configurable:!0}}),t&&_setPrototypeOf(e,t)}function _setPrototypeOf(e,t){return(_setPrototypeOf=Object.setPrototypeOf||function(e,t){return e.__proto__=t,e})(e,t)}var H1LikeButton=function(e){function t(e){var n;return _classCallCheck(this,t),(n=_possibleConstructorReturn(this,_getPrototypeOf(t).call(this,e))).state={isLiked:!1},n.handleClick=n.handleClick.bind(_assertThisInitialized(n)),n}return _inherits(t,React.Component),_createClass(t,[{key:"handleClick",value:function(){this.setState(function(e){return{isLiked:!e.isLiked}})}},{key:"render",value:function(){return React.createElement(React.Fragment,null,this.state.isLiked&&React.createElement("p",null,"This is liked."),React.createElement("h1",{onClick:this.handleClick},!this.state.isLiked?"Like":"Dislike"))}}]),t}(),LikeButton=function(e){function t(e){var n;return _classCallCheck(this,t),(n=_possibleConstructorReturn(this,_getPrototypeOf(t).call(this,e))).state={isLiked:!1},n.handleClick=n.handleClick.bind(_assertThisInitialized(n)),n}return _inherits(t,React.Component),_createClass(t,[{key:"handleClick",value:function(){this.setState(function(e){return{isLiked:!e.isLiked}})}},{key:"render",value:function(){return React.createElement("div",null,this.state.isLiked&&React.createElement("p",null,"This is liked."),React.createElement("button",{onClick:this.handleClick},!this.state.isLiked?"Like":"Dislike"),React.createElement("br",null),React.createElement(H1LikeButton,null))}}]),t}();ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(LikeButton,null),document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So... compile everything into a single file, or... you'll have to use a [third party library](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/How-to-include-a-JavaScript-file-in-another-JavaScript-file.html) that allows importing/exporting js files.

Working repo example (using [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/)): https://github.com/mattcarlotta/standalone-requirejs-example

Some tools to help you:

- [Compile Babel ES6+ to ES5 JS](https://babeljs.io/en/repl)
- [Javascript Minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/)

In short, it's uncommon to not use some sort of bundler (webpack, rollup, gulp, parcel, browserify, ...etc), so while it's possible to work with JSX in development, you'll still want to compile it for production. By not being able to use node and a bundler, expect to be handicapped throughout development/production.

Comment: Updated answer to include note about JSX.